# Installing Ubuntu on Windows 2000 Pro laptop

Tags: boot

I have an old laptop running Windows 2000 Pro that one belonged to a domain.  I can no longer remember my password to log on to it.  I therefore want to install Ubuntu.  Is this possible from Boot?

Comment: Does it have a DVD player or is capable of boot from USB? Since Ubuntu no longer fits on a CD those are the only aviable options that occur to me, you might also want to provide the model of your laptop and consider Xubuntu or Lubuntu instead of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can, you just create a installation dvd or usb and boot from that. in the installation you choose to replace windows and you have a Ubuntu pc! I can give you a full description on how to install Ubuntu but you can find it [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-desktop-long-term-support)

Comment: Ubuntu no longer fits on a CD sadly

Comment: you are right edited...

Comment: 12.04 does, doesn't it?

Comment: 707MB iso doesn't fit on 700MB CD